# How to render view only after selection in yii2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I am rendering two views in my single view.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 't_type')->dropDownList([
    '' => 'Please Select', 'Slab Based' => 'Slab Based',
    'TOU Based' => 'TOU Based']) ?>

<div class="showSlab" id="slab" style="display: none">
    <?php echo $this->render('_slabBased', [
        'modelsTariffSlabs' => $modelsTariffSlabs,
    ]); ?>
</div>

<div class="showTou" id="tou" style="display: none">

    <?php echo $this->render('_touBased', [
        'modelsTouSlabs' => $modelsTouSlabs,
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

By default both div's are hidden but both of them are rendering. But I want to render the form only when I select option 'Slab Based' or `TOU Based`

**JS**

```
$('#mdctariff-t_type').on('change', function () {
    if (this.value === 'Slab Based') {
        $("#slab").show();
        $("#tou").hide();


    } else if (this.value === 'TOU Based') {
        $("#tou").show();
        $("#slab").hide();


    } else {
        $("#slab").hide();
        $("#tou").hide();

    }
});
```

**Note:** After rendering the form I am also saving it

**Update 1**

I have tried to render it via `ajax`

```
$url = Url::toRoute(['/mdctariff/_slabBased','modelsTariffSlabs'=>$modelsTariffSlabs]);

doGet('$url')

function doGet(url, params) {
        params = params || {};

        $.get(url, params, function(response) { // requesting url which in form
            $('#slab').html(response); // getting response and pushing to element with id #response
        });
    }
```

**Reference:** [How to render partial using AJAX? Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37647328/6854117)

When I selects an option I am not able to view the form. In my `Network` tab I am getting error `Not Found (#404): Page not found.`. The `URL` generated is `http://localhost/mdc/backend/web/mdctariff/_slabBased`

While pasting this URL at my browser I am getting the same error. I must be missing something that I don't know

How can render my view only when I select an option?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use AJAX and load it dynamically.

Comment: so you dont want to show hide by pre-loading the form in the body ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yes I want to show the form only when an option is selected

Comment: @Bizley I have tried but still unable to get the desired result.

Comment: I am not able to understand your question, do you want to hide everything on page load? have you specified your ajax path in `routes\web.php` ?

Comment: @Rafay not everything. When page loads I am hiding the `divs`. But the page inside the `divs` are rendered. I want to stop this. `_touBased` or `slabBased` should only be rendered on selection.

Comment: `http://localhost/mdc/backend/web/mdctariff/_slabBased` looks a bit strange. I suggest url should be `http://localhost/mdctariff/_slabBased`, could you check it?

Comment: @ExploitFate no the `url` is correct

Answer (score 2):

In your URL

`$url = Url::toRoute(['/mdctariff/_slabBased','modelsTariffSlabs'=>$modelsTariffSlabs]);`

The first argument should be the proper existing route. But you have written it in the form of a directory, i.e. `mdctafiff` folder then `_slabBased` file.

What you need to do here is, you need to create an action method in the controller so that you can access it through route. Like `MdctariffController` and `partialAction` and then in the body of `partialAction` method you need to call the `_slabBased` view file. Futher you can also take reference [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-url) for Url::toRoute().

Comment: So dropdown select I have to call that particular controller via `ajax`?

Comment: Yes, the very first perameter to `Url::toRoute()` should be `controllerName/actionName`.